# Determining which accounts are to be credited/debited

Tags: c#, linq, finance

I recently discovered/came across [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) and have been trying to learn and utilize its features. Here's my first function `UpdateTransactionsData()`. This method is for a `PurchaseDocument` class which I have included partially. Basically this function loops through the selected items on the `PurchaseDocument`, and works out which accounts (chart of accounts, as per accounting) are to be credited/debited for each purchased item.

After I have populated the dictionary properties with the transaction amounts, I use Linq to first remove all the transactions with amount 0 and then to generate XML elements to represent the transactions (provided a sample of the output).

The code works. Am I using LINQ right? Is the code optimal? Can I improve the LINQ code? Should I even be using it?

**XmlOutput**

```xml
<Debit Account="26" Amount="36" />
<Debit Account="24" Amount="188.7" />
<Debit Account="80" Amount="-29.21" />
<Credit Account="57" Amount="253.91" />
<Inventory Item="22007" Adjustment="10" />
<Inventory Item="11389" Adjustment="5" />
```

**PurchaseDocument.cs**

```cs
public class PurchaseDocument
{
    public Dictionary<int, double> DebitTransactions = new Dictionary<int, double>();
    public Dictionary<int, double> CreditTransactions = new Dictionary<int, double>();
    public Dictionary<int, double> InventoryTransactions = new Dictionary<int, double>();

    #region public ObservableCollection<PurchaseDocumentItem> Items;
    private ObservableCollection<PurchaseDocumentItem> _Items = new ObservableCollection<PurchaseDocumentItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<PurchaseDocumentItem> Items
    {
        get { return _Items; }
        set
        {
            string property = "Items";
            OnPropertyChanging(property);
            _Items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(property);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private void UpdateTransactionsData()
    {
        DebitTransactions.Clear();
        CreditTransactions.Clear();
        InventoryTransactions.Clear();
        Entity.TransactionsData = "";

        foreach (PurchaseDocumentItem item in Items.Where(x => x.InventoryItem != null))
        {
            // asset and expense transactions
            int account = (item.InventoryItem.IsService) ? item.InventoryItem.CogsAccountID : item.InventoryItem.AssetAccountID;
            if(!DebitTransactions.ContainsKey(account))
                DebitTransactions.Add(account, 0);
            DebitTransactions[account] += item.Amount;

            // inventory transaction
            if (!item.InventoryItem.IsService)
            {
                if(!InventoryTransactions.ContainsKey(item.ItemID))
                    InventoryTransactions.Add(item.ItemID, 0);
                InventoryTransactions[item.ItemID] += item.Quantity;
            }
        }

        // tax transaction
        int taxaccount = Session.Company.PurchasesTaxAccountID;
        if(!DebitTransactions.ContainsKey(taxaccount))
            DebitTransactions.Add(taxaccount, 0);
        DebitTransactions[taxaccount] -= (double)Tax;

        // freight transaction
        int freightaccount = Session.Company.FreightExpenseAccountID;
        if(!DebitTransactions.ContainsKey(freightaccount))
            DebitTransactions.Add(freightaccount, 0);
        DebitTransactions[freightaccount] += (double)Freight;

        // payables transaction
        int payablesaccount = Session.Company.AccountsPayableID;
        if(!CreditTransactions.ContainsKey(payablesaccount))
            CreditTransactions.Add(payablesaccount, 0);
        CreditTransactions[payablesaccount] += (double)Total;

        // take out all transaction with amount 0
        DebitTransactions = DebitTransactions.Where(x => x.Value != 0).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        CreditTransactions = CreditTransactions.Where(x => x.Value != 0).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        InventoryTransactions = InventoryTransactions.Where(x => x.Value != 0).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

        // convert the data to xml
        Entity.TransactionsData += DebitTransactions.Aggregate("", (data, t) => data + "<Debit Account=\"" + t.Key.ToString()  + "\" Amount=\"" + t.Value.ToString() + "\" />" + Environment.NewLine);
        Entity.TransactionsData += CreditTransactions.Aggregate("", (data, t) => data + "<Credit Account=\"" + t.Key.ToString() + "\" Amount=\"" + t.Value.ToString() + "\" />" + Environment.NewLine);
        Entity.TransactionsData += InventoryTransactions.Aggregate("", (data, t) => data + "<Inventory Item=\"" + t.Key.ToString() + "\" Adjustment=\"" + t.Value.ToString() + "\" />" + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem with the LINQ you have.

If you wanted, you could use a little bit of LINQ to get rid of that foreach loop you have.  You can create two LINQ queries to query the Items collection, group accounts/items together, and return the sum of the Amounts/Quantities as a Dictionary:

```
DebitTransactions = (from item in Items
                     where item.InventoryItem != null

                     let account = (item.InventoryItem.IsService) ? item.InventoryItem.CogsAccountID : item.InventoryItem.AssetAccountID

                     group item by account into itemGroup
                     select new 
                     {
                        Account = itemGroup.Key,
                        Amount = itemGroup.Sum(i => i.Amount)
                     }).ToDictionary(k => k.Account, v => v.Amount);

InventoryTransactions = (from item in Items
                         where item.InventoryItem != null && !item.InventoryItem.IsService

                         group item by item.ItemID into itemGroup
                         select new
                         {
                            ItemID = itemGroup.Key
                            Quantity = itemGroup.Sum(i => i.Quantity)
                         }).ToDictionary(k => k.ItemID, v => v.Quantity);
```

It's a little more messy and probably a little less efficient, but good for learning LINQ.

Comment: Ahh that's great, thanks for your help! Learning a few more things from your code :)